# Smarty {include} File+Tag If exists, otherwise fallback to File

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I'm working on a white label product, and would like to be able to quickly overwrite some templates but not all of them.

My idea is to have something of the kind, in say `index.tpl`

```
{include file="header.tpl" tag=$whitelabelname} 
{include file="body.tpl" tag=$whitelabelname} 
{include file="footer.tpl" tag=$whitelabelname}
```

I'd like to be able, if there's any way to do it, to automatically include the file header-whitelabelname.tpl if exists, or header.tpl if it doesn't.

```
$tagTemplate = substr($template, 0, -4) . "-" . $tag . ".tpl";
if ( file_exists($tagTemplate) ) $template = $tagTemplate;
```

The reason for doing this is the alternative would need to change all template files to a big switch statement on each and every include, which would end up with very large and complex templates.

Is it possible to extend the `{include}` directive somehow to include my logic, rather than changing smarty_internal_compile_include.php manually myself.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to change the Smarty compiler, Smarty can be extended in many, many ways by implementing plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing a [Smarty resource plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.resources.tpl). Check the example on the documentation page. You have to implement your `file_exists()` logic into the first function. Also check the method [register_resource()](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.register.resource.tpl) about how to use the plugin.